# How to prevent nginx from sending Strict-Transport-Security header?

Tags: ssl, nginx, headers, hsts

I recently added https support to my site with nginx reverse proxy.

I do not have `add_header Strict-Transport-Security ...` line in my config.
Even then, I see `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400` in response header.

If I add `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0; includeSubDomains";` in my config, I get *two* headers in response!!:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.11.12 is not blacklisted
Server: nginx/1.11.12
Date: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 11:46:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 37
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Surrogate-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked all nginx config files? Final configuration is usually merged from several. Try running `grep -r 'Strict-Transport-Security'` from `/etc/nginx/` folder. Check also in `/usr/local/nginx` if it exists.

Comment: Also, welcome to SuperUser :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it was my application server that emitted the first header when it found itself on secure connection.

Anybody using `helmet` plugin, refer [this](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hsts/) to manage it in your app.

Comment: Flag the answer as solution then.